# MS SQL Server 2008/2012 Get Min Difference between any two values

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

Given a table with a single `money` column how do I calculate the smallest difference between any two values in that table using `TSQL`? I'm looking for the performance optimized solution, which will work with millions of rows.

Comment: Yes I deleted my comment as I hadn't spotted that. Will post it again for posterity! `SELECT MAX(col) - MIN(col)` with an index on the column will work for the greatest part.

Comment: It most certainly will, at it's quite fast, the challenge is the smallest one:(

Comment: I'll re-phrase the question to avoid confusion, will I?

Comment: You could use `LAG` to compare current and previous row in index order and use a query with `TOP 1` to exit if it ever evaluates to zero. But if you don't find any two values that are the same this will still need to scan all rows. You could maybe have this precalculated.

Comment: Could you post that up in a form of TSQL?

Comment: It's just a sketch of an idea and I haven't got 2012 installed on this machine to test it and look at execution plans. I will later if no one comes up with a more concrete answer in the meantime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For SQL Server 2012 you could use

```
;WITH CTE
     AS (SELECT YourColumn - Lag(YourColumn) OVER (ORDER BY YourColumn) AS Diff
         FROM   YourTable)
SELECT 
      Min(Diff) AS MinDiff
FROM   CTE
```

This does it with one scan of the table (ideally you would have an index on `YourColumn` to avoid a sort and a narrow index on that single column would reduce IO).

I can't think of a nice way of getting it to short circuit and so do less than one scan of the table if it finds the minimum possible difference of zero. Adding `MIN(CASE WHEN Diff = 0 THEN 1/0 END)` to the `SELECT` list and trapping the divide by zero error as a signal that zero was found would probably work but I can't really recommend that approach...